# How do I set my iPhone / iPad to UTC-12 time zone?

Tags: iphone, ios, timezone

It seems the latest time zone is UTC-12, as listed on the [Wikipedia UTC time offsets article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets).  But on the iPhone / iPad, I cannot find and choose the time zone of either "Baker Island" or "Howland Island". How could it be done?

Comment: Since UTC-12 has no inhabitants at all and is only used by ships, it’s quite likely that Apple didn’t bother to implement it as an option.

Comment: people on ships need love too ;)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be possible to set UTC-12 in the *Date & Time* section in *Preferences* (see below for more on that).

But I was able to spoof my location with Xcode and a GPS file with these contents:

```
<gpx>
    <wpt lat="0.194722" lon="-176.479444"></wpt>
</gpx>
```

as explained in [Using Xcode to Test Location Services](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/04/using-xcode-to-test-location-services/). The Simulator app thought I was on Baker Island (this is a screenshot of the Maps app showing my current location):

[image]

This suggests that you could, with the help of a Mac running Xcode, set your iPhone's time zone to UTC-12. I couldn't test it because I don't have a developer account, and one is needed to sign and run apps on an iPhone.

**As for the usual method of setting the time with the *Date & Time* section in *Preferences*:** as I said above that doesn't seem to be possible.

According the Apple support article [Get help with the date and time on your iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203483), to manually set the time zone you have to "tap Time Zone and enter a city with the time zone that you need".

But Wikipedia's [UTC-12 article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9212:00) tells us that UTC−12 is a nautical time zone and although a number of inhabited islands lie within the longitudinal limits of this time zone, **none of them keeps the date and time of UTC−12**.

So there are no cities to choose, and none of these names (from obvious to obscure) are recognized:

- Baker Island
- Howland Island
- UTC-12
- US Minor Outlying Islands
- Anywhere on Earth
- AoE
- International Date Line West time zone
- IDLW

I wonder if turning on "Set Automatically" would properly adjust the time for someone visiting Baker Island...

Comment: Does Baker Island have a cell site?

Comment: I believe XCode has the ability to simulate the device being in a certain GPS location which I haven't done before, but so it probably is possible to test the "Set Automatically" as if you are at that location

Comment: @太極者無極而生 Tried that, unfortunately, the Date & Time section is not available in the Simulator app, sigh...

Comment: @jaume what about connecting to a real iPhone?  I heard people can connect an iPhone to a Mac with XCode and then change the GPS on the Mac and make the iPhone believe it is at that location

Comment: @太極者無極而生 I don't have a developer account so I can't test it with an iPhone, but I was able to change the location in the Simulator app so that Maps displayed my position as being in Baker Island.